# BeautifulSoup parse the input with missing tag

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-2.7

```
> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup str = '<p><input></input></p>'
> BeautifulSoup(str, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
> <p><input /></p>
```

why the output misses the  tag? It should print `<p><input></input></p>`, but why it transforms to `<p><input /></p>`?

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<input />` is a valid shorthand for `<input></input>`. This is true for HTML and XML. You might be able to convince BeautifulSoup to output the expanded version, but I don't see why you would want this.

Comment: Yes I do, in terms of parsing rather than changing the content.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want BeautifulSoup to replicate the input exactly?